# why dont jQuery work on two Ids with same names?

Tags: jquery

I have .ims and .content,  two ids but my code working on only for parent id #one

```
<html>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="ims">show some content</div> 
        <div id="content"> hello world</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="ims">show some content</div> 
        <div id="content"> hello world</div> 
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#content").hide();
            $("#ims").click(function () {
                $("#ims").slideUp("slow");
                $("#content").slideDown("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique on document context to get valid HTML markup, that's why...

Comment: Use classes if you need repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same `id` for different elements. `id`s must be unique. Use `class` instead.

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="ims">show some content</div> 
    <div class="content"> hello world</div> 
</div>
<div id="two">
    <div class="ims">show some content</div> 
    <div class="content"> hello world</div> 
<div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide(); // Hide all .contents
    $(".ims").click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp("slow").siblings(".content").slideDown("slow"); // Hide current ims & show sibling with class content
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j61t7qww/1/)

Comment: Thank you b0s3 for helping me, Hope someone would burn this useless IE.

Answer (score 1):

`Id` should be unique use `class` instead of id

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="ims">show some content</div>
    <div class="content">hello world</div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <div class="ims">show some content</div>
    <div class="content">hello world</div>
    <div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".ims").click(function () {
       $(this).slideUp("slow").next(".content").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7nntj44n/)**